# What is the difference between vanilla css and modular css

Tags: css, smacss

I went through an machine test where I was allowed to convert a PSD template into a HTML using `vanilla css` and `modular css`.

I tried searching for both but couldn't find something related to vanilla css.

However searching more deep I got a very good result with modular css. Here is the [link](https://smacss.com/).

Any thought will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi! I hope this would you useful to you. : https://www.npmjs.com/package/vanilla-css

Comment: Thanks for the link. Don't you think its a plain css and nothing more than that ? What makes it call vanilla css from just a css ?

Comment: @Santhosh I just don't know man. Did you see in the downloads section? Are they making fool out of us? It's a plain css. Ain't it?

Comment: @HarishankarAyandev Exactly!  take a look at this link. This is really crazy. https://github.com/aethant/vanilla-css/issues/13

Comment: Man! They are making us waste our time by wasting theirs. Let's go do our job.

Comment: https://github.com/aethant/vanilla-css/issues/36 Also! Did you see the reply here? :'D I wonder how it's being displayed in npm's official site.

Comment: I can't control my laughter. lolz..   `That's the magic of vanilla css. It's everywhere among us. It's apart of us. It needs no demo site.`

Comment: Haha! yeah. Very crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between them rather than how you structure your `css`.
Think of modular css as a style of writing vanilla (i.e. normal) css.

In modular CSS, the CSS is grouped by modules. Robin Rendle wrote a good article about these [css modules](https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-1-need/).

It's merely a set of guidelines, on how to approach your `css` architecture and name your classes.

The reasoning is pretty simple, if you use `smacss`, for instance, anyone that joins your team can learn the `smacss` principles and start working on all of your projects.

Have a look at `BEM`, `SMACSS`, `ITCSS`, or `OOCSS`.

Comment: So vanilla is a plain css just like a plain Ice Cream ? nothing more ? I preety much like the idea of smacss. Thanks anyway

Comment: "vanilla" is used as an adjective for "having no special or extra features; ordinary or standard" :) So yep, plain ice cream